# Can't load debug symbols VS2017 - Unity .NET 4.X

Tags: .net, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, debugging, pdb-files

I'm using a .NET 4.7.1 library I've built, in a Unity 2018.4.2 Windows project and trying to debug with symbols loaded. No matter what I try, I can't get the symbols to load for the library while debugging in Visual Studio 2017 (15.9.12). The following appears next to my DLL in modules window:

> Symbol status: Not Loaded

Here's what I've tried:

1. Build library as Debug
2. *Absolutely* ensure current PDB matches current DLL
3. Modules>Symbol Settings>Add the PDB dir to Symbol File locations
4. Copy the PDB file into the project next to the DLL
5. Scripting Runtime 4.X, API Compat. 4.X in Unity
6. Debug standalone builds & editor
7. Opened the library with ILSpy, debug symbols loaded correctly
8. Right click DLL in VS Modules Window & click 'Symbol Load information' - Nothing at all happens
9. Right click DLL in VS Modules Window & click 'Load Symbols'  -

When clicking Load Symbols, the following appears ->

[image]

But symbol status remains 'Not Loaded'

Comment: Use the Modules toolwindow to dbl check the path that the DLL is actually being loaded from, in most instances where you have the dll and pdb sitting side by side, where the VS debugger refuses to load the PDB, you are most likely loading the DLL from some other path. And consequently loading one that doesn't match up. When the linker creates the binary and the pdb, it generates a guid to mark both. The VS debugger checks the guid in the binary and any pdbs it attempts to load. If they don't match, it won't load.

Comment: While in editor mode, the module DLL paths are as expected. Builds of course move these files to a build directory. If configured (in player settings) the PDB files will be copied as well (next to the new path of the DLLs).

Comment: I've logged this as a bug with Microsoft here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/678520/vstu-2017-debug-symbols-not-loading.html

Comment: I am still having the same problem in 2020.
Were you able to solve this issue or did you give up all hope?

Comment: I gave up, unfortunately :(

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out after struggling with it as well.

I believe the problem originated from when I installed Visual Studio before Unity.

What fixed it for me was:

In Unity -> Edit -> Preferences -> External Tools -> (change the external script editor to what you want and ensure it's proper IE: I had mine set to visual studio 2019 however it needed Visual Studio 2019 (Enterprise))

this was despite the *same instance of visual studio opening* -- it looks like its something on Unity's side that's causing the problem.

This solved it for me and I hope it helps you too.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution from this post: https://forum.unity.com/threads/problems-debugging-my-plugin-dlls-in-visual-studio.506577/

**Your Project Property Window**->**Build**->**Advanced**->**Debugging Information** choose **Portable**.

Rebuild and done!